# Can't integrate AssertJ into TestNG (Java 1.8, Maven)

Tags: assertj

[image]

1. Added dependency into pom.xml

[image]

2. After adding static import (tried also many with all list) and assertion (AssertThat) - it doesn't work.
   import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

It's not finding any JAR for AssertJ. After pressing 2 times control+space - there are no suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen AssertJ working with Idea, please double check  your classpath in Idea.

You can check hos maven resolve your dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree`, you should see something like:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ assertj-examples-java-8 ---
[INFO] org.assertj:assertj-examples-java-8:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.12.2-SNAPSHOT:test
```